# how to get to know my payment providers name while calling google pay API?

Tags: android, android-pay, google-pay

How to get to know my payment providers name while calling google pay API ?
I am referring below code.

```
private fun gatewayTokenizationSpecification(): JSONObject {
    return JSONObject().apply {
        put("type", "PAYMENT_GATEWAY")
        put("parameters", JSONObject(mapOf(
                "gateway" to "example",   // HOW TO GET this value
                "gatewayMerchantId" to "exampleGatewayMerchantId")))
    }
}
```

HOW to get gateway value ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Request a payment token for your payment provider](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#tokenization) section on the tutorial page includes a list of supported payment gateways. There's a text field that you can use to search for your payment provider which will show you the required fields.